# Function to Check if POST is empty and add custom error messages

Tags: php, arrays, function, validation

I have some code to check an empty post like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if (empty($_POST[$key]))
        {
            $errors[] = "$key" . "is empty.";
        }
    }
```

how can i add some custom messages because using $key + is empty isn't good enough for me. i want to display custom messages for every post. maybe some function like validate($name, Please enter your name, required). but i don't have a clue how to do it, can anyone can provide me some method i can try?

Comment: You can simply loop the $errors array and display this errors, can't you?

Comment: yes but it will print like first_name is empty, meanwhile all i want is to print Please enter your first name.

Comment: and if it email post it will post error like "Please enter your email" not customer_email is empty. hope you catch what i mean here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a custom message depending on the key, you should just use a switch.

```
$errors = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (empty($value))
    {
        switch($key) {
            case 'name':
                $errors[] = "The name is empty.";
                break;
            case 'age':
                $errors[] = "The age is empty.";
                break;
            default:
                $errors[] = $key . " is empty.";
        }
    }
}
```

*** Edit ***

If you want to do special treatment according to the key, and use a function :

```
$errors = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $result = validate($key, $value);
    if (!empty($result)) {
        $errors[] = $result;
    }
}

function validate($key, $value) {
    if ($key == 'name' && empty($value)) {
        return 'You must enter your name';
    }
    elseif ($key == 'age' && empty($value)) {
        return 'You must enter your date of birth';
    }
    elseif ($key == 'email' && filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        return 'Your email is incorrect';
    }

    return '';
}
```

Comment: how i can switch if it's not required paramater, how about if i want to validate email? that's why i write validate($name, custom messages here, required)

Comment: check my edited answer, better suits your need I guess

Answer (score 1):

Check for Form Validation scripts/tutorials with PHP.

Here are some quick findings:

1. Using modular approach: http://www.sitepoint.com/form-validation-with-php/
2. Using class based (OOP) approach: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use same approach, then use this

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (empty($_POST[$key]))
    {
        $errors[] = getValidationMessage($key);
    }
}

function getValidationMessage($key){

    if($key == "user_name")
        return "please enter user name.";
    else if ($key == "date_of_birth")
        return "please enter you date of birth";

    //and so on, 

    //based on param names in your html-forms
}
```

Comment: do you have some function than can make me switch if it's not required paramater,so if i want to validate email  i write validate($email, custom messages here, email)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $errors[] = validate($k);
}

function validate($key) {
    if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'name':
                $message = "Name is empty";
                break;
            case 'email':
                $message = "fill in your email address";
                break;
            default:
                $message = $key." is empty";
                break;
        }

        return $message;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes actually i just want to call the funtion without foreach like Validate($name, custom messages here, required)